# MySQL SELECT only AVAILABLE months from rows with DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

I have a table which goes like

```
 id    |    title    |    text    |    time_and_date (DATETIME)
```

Now I want to find out what months are there available,

there can be 0-X rows containing same month in time_and_date.

Or even better what months are available according to my WHERE in query (I got that part already done).

So from table like

```
   id     |     title      |     text      |    time_and_date (DATETIME)
    5     |    'title1'    |    'text1'    |    '2008-12-24 07:00:00'
    7     |    'title2'    |    'text2'    |    '2008-11-24 12:20:11'
   20     |    'title3'    |    'text3'    |    '2008-08-24 06:00:57'
    1     |    'title4'    |    'text4'    |    '2008-08-24 19:20:45'
```

The result should look like

```
12
11
08
```

Note that:

1) if there are more rows with the same month, the month is returned only once

2) if there is no row with some month - that month is not returned at all.

I know (I guess) this is some perfect "for `GROUP BY` case", but I just can't figure out how would I structure this query.

I will be thankful even for a pointing out the right direction :-)

## My final solution

"**select only current or future available years+months**" in entries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(time_and_date) month, YEAR(time_and_date) year
 FROM entries
 WHERE time_and_date>=NOW()
 ORDER BY time_and_date DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(time_and_date) AS month
```

`DISTINCT` means that will return each occurence of value only once, `MONTH()` returns only month (not whole date), the `AS` part isn't mandatory (just to make column name "normal")

Comment: nice one, however - doesnt this require for DB to convert all rows' time_and_date columns first? (it would not matter in this particular case, but for about 10 000 to 100 000 rows it could)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how exactly SQL handles such queries, but it has to read (and convert) each row - how else would it found what month it is. BTW I just run this query on my 170,000-row table, and it took 0.3 sec. to run this query (and my machine isn't anything special, so I guess there is nothing to worry about

Comment: Looks optimized then :) Thanks for answer && testing :)

Comment: @jave.web Sorry I just realize that I have index on the column I was trying this query :D (and I really don't have many indexed columns...) - I just tried it on one non-indexed-column of same table and it took 4 sec - which isn't so awesome, but still not so bad. Furthermore I doubt there is a faster way.